# Attempting to create bootable USB for 2012 Macbook Pro with high Sierra but can't locate a pkg file for MacOS

Tags: high-sierra

I'm attempting to create bootable USB with high Sierra for installation on an old 2012 Macbook Pro but can't locate a pkg file for MacOS. When trying to download this version on my 2022 Mac obviously Apple are not allowing it as it wont run on this new M2 machine.

For the life of me I can't find a downloadable file for high Sierra. Can anyone assist with this or perhaps a work around that will allow me to download it from the Appstore?

Cheers.

Comment: @Allan My view is that the answers to that question are, in many cases, no longer useful.

Comment: You can download HS from Apple using either MDS https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/ or Mist https://github.com/ninxsoft/Mist (download is here https://github.com/ninxsoft/Mist/releases). Mist is easier.

Comment: @Gilby - I ought to add that info to the top of my answer. I agree it's been expanded so much over the years that it's only vaguely relevant half the time these days. I might give it a good, solid updating if I get the time - there are for instance refs to when all the certificates timed out that don't need all that explanation any more. I think it may still be best overall to have the one comprehensive answer to an issue that crops up frequently in many guises.

Comment: Answer updated.. hope I managed to lift some of the more relevant info to the top & demote the oldest/least useful.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't envy you trying to keep that answer up to date :). I have added a comment to it re Mist/MDS not doing older than HS.

Comment: @Gilby - thanks. Yeah, as time has gone on there are more & more elements I can't test myself - OS too new, OS too old. I have hardware from 2008 to 2020, but testing some of the solutions is impractical. I'm going to have a go, possibly over the next week or so, of *actually* testing whether some of the ideas remaining in there still work. Some days I think the solution to this would be to put all the installers up on Mega - but that would introduce trust issues, amongst other things.